Is there a general way to find the inverse of an automorphism of the free group?
If we describe an automorphism of the free group (on n generators) by where it sends the generators, is there some kind of algorithm to find the inverse automorphism? I am particularly interested in outer automorphisms.

Yes. Let $X$ be the given (ordered) free generating set of the free group, and let $Y$ be the set of images of the elements of $X$ under the automorphism.
Now perform Nielsen reduction on $Y$, and with each operation on $Y$, perform the same operation on $X$. Since $Y$ generates the group, Nielsen reduction will transform $Y$ back to $X$ and at the same time you are replacing $X$ by the set of inverse images of the the elements of $X$ under the automorphism.
Added later: Sorry, Nielsen reduction does not always work in general (although it seems to work on straightforward examples) and when it fails to reduce $Y$ to $X$ you have to use a more complicated set of reductions known as Whitehead automorphisms.
There is another method, which is more general and can be applied to an automorphism of any group $G=\langle X \mid R \rangle$ defined by a finite presentation that maps $X$ to $Y$. You carry out a modified version of the Todd-Coxeter coset enumeration on the subgroup $H=\langle Y \rangle$ of $G$. The index of the subgroup is of course $1$ and this should be successfully computed but, whereas  basic coset enumeration just computes the coset table entries $Hg_ix = Hg_j$ for $x \in X$, the modified version also computes the corresponding $h \in H$ with $g_ix = hg_j$ as words over $Y$. So in this case, where there is only one coset, we end of with expressions for the elements $x \in X$ as words over $Y$, which is exactly what you are trying to compute.

I particularly like how your description of this process mirrors the process for inverting a matrix: "Now perform row reduction on $Y$, and with each row operation on $Y$ perform the same operation on the identity matrix..."
